# How can I resolve this segmentation fault?

Tags: c, multithreading, segmentation-fault

This is my assignment brief.

Write a multithreaded program that calculates statistical values for a list of numbers. This
program will be passed a series of numbers on the command line and will then create a
worker threads. Which will determine the average of the numbers.

I've spent more time on this than I wish to say, I still haven't had the chance to see if the code actually works (obviously it doesn't if I've got a segmentation fault). The only message I get for the fault is "zsh: segmentation fault".

Here's part of my code, any help is appreciated.

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

/* Variables that hold the final results, integer data type for simplicity */
int avgNum;
int numNum;
int i;
int sum = 0;

/* Functions' declaration. Definition is at the bottom*/
void *avgfunc(void *param);

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    numNum = argc;
    
    /*Creating the thread ids*/
    pthread_t tid0;

    /*Creating the threads*/
    pthread_create(&tid0, NULL, avgfunc, (int *)&avgNum);

    /*Enabling the threads to operate simultaneously*/
    pthread_join(tid0, NULL);

    /*Exiting the threads*/
    pthread_exit(NULL);

    /*Outputing the final average, maximum and minimum results*/
    printf("Average: %d", avgNum);
}

void *avgfunc(void *param)
{
    char** args = (char**) param;   
    args++;                        

    if(numNum > 1)
    {
        for(i = 1; i < numNum; i++)
        {
            sum += atoi(args[i]);
        }
        avgNum = sum / numNum;
    }
}
```

This is my first project on C, and my first in general in about 2 years so I have no idea where to start.

Comment: You are passing pointer to avgNum as the argument to your thread. But the thread is assuming it is receiving a list of strings as input and tries to access the regions of memory which it should not. That is why your program is terminated by receiving a SEGFAULT.

Comment: `avgfunc` expects an array as input. You're passing a pointer to a single `int`. Fixed that you can fix the average: you're not (I suppose...) dealing with `char[]` but `int[]` then what youre doing inside `avgfunc` makes little sense

Comment: "This is my first project on C" Don't start with multi-threading, which is a relatively advanced topic.

Comment: Your first task should be to convert the strings in the array `argv` to an array of `int` elements. I recommend that you use the function [`strtol`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtol) for converting the individual elements.

Comment: @Lundin unfortunately this is not something i had the pleasure of choosing to do

Comment: @Spxnje: You may find using the function [`atoi`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/atoi) simpler than [`strtol`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtol). The disadvantage of using `atoi` is that it won't tell you if a conversion error occurred. With the function `strtol`, it is possible to determine whether this happened. See the linked documentation for further information.

Answer (score 2):

Lots of problems:

- You don't actually do anything with `argv` nor do you check if `argc` is correct. As told by the compiler if you enable warnings and pay attention to them.
- `avgNum` is a global variable (and as such initialized to zero), it has no relation to anything at all in your program. Still you pass this to the thread callback.
- `(int *)&avgNum` Casting from `int*` to `int*` is senseless.
- `char** args = (char**) param;` here `param` is pointing at the above mentioned useless `avgNum` integer.
- Your thread callback is missing a return statement despite being of the form `void*` so when the function ends you invoke undefined behavior. As told by the compiler if you enable warnings and pay attention to them.

Next step before doing anything else: [What compiler options are recommended for beginners learning C?](https://software.codidact.com/posts/282565)

Another good rule of thumb for beginners is to *never cast pointers*. There is no reason to do so in this program. A `void*` can be implicitly converted to/from any other object pointer type. All you achieve with casts here is bugs/hiding away bugs. Weird casts like these can also be a sign of a beginner using the completely wrong compiler, namely a C++ one. And using a C++ compiler to compile C code won't end well.

Comment: `[avgNum] has no relation to anything at all in the program. Still you pass this to the thread callback.` -- This statement is not quite correct. `avgNum` is supposed to store the result of the operation, so it does make sense to pass a pointer to it to the thread. However, the thread does not use the passed pointer for this purpose, and instead accesseses `avgNum` directly, instead of via the passed pointer.